# How can I map keys in Insert mode that contains Carriage Return in it?

Tags: vim, text, insert, editor, vi

How can I map `ctrl + enter` to go to new line from anywhere  in the current line in vim ?
I just want to do it for `insert` mode.
I tried

> :set <C-<CR>> <Esc>o

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't - Vim can't recognise Ctrl-Enter. Then again, `<Esc>o` is not any more complex than Ctrl-Enter - why do you even want that?

Comment: Why not simply `<End><CR>`? It's not really harder than `<C-CR>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an insert mode mapping, you need `:imap`; `:set` is for setting Vim options. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is written as `<C-CR>`; cp. `:help key-notation`. Ergo:

```
:inoremap <C-CR> <Esc>o
```

Note that this key combination mostly only works in GVIM, as most terminals do not send different keycodes for <kbd>Enter</kbd> in combination with modifier keys. If you need a solution that also works in terminals, you need another key (combo), e.g. `<C-g><CR>`.

Comment: Dear Ingo, care to explain better what is `<c-g>` about? Hard to google for it.

Comment: @DrBeco: Ctrl + G is just one of the few key combinations that isn't taken by default in insert mode, so it's suitable for such custom mapping.

Answer (score 1):

### For Windows Users:

---

#### Solution 1

[On windows Terminal-App, CMD or Powershell the `Ctrl+Enter` is getting translated to `Ctrl+j`](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/6912) and so you can do:

```
:inoremap <C-j> <ESC>o
```

```lua
vim.keymap.set('i', '<C-j>', '<ESC>o')
```

[image: Demonstration]

---

#### Solution 2

The preferred way is to use the "Keyboard Manager" utility of **PowerToys** and target any app you want to [remap it's keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager#remap-shortcuts), like:
[image: PowerToys Keyboard Manager utility]

---

### References:

- [Add new line after current line in insert mode vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061469/)
- [Can terminals detect <Shift-Enter> or <Control-Enter>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598113/)
- [How to insert a newline without leaving normal mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3875/)
- [remapping  in vim?](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/aaxpxi/remapping_ctrlenter_in_vim/)