# can't map alt+enter using gvim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map `<A-CR>` using gvim 7.4.

When I map `<A-...>` or `<S-CR>` they work fine, but when I try to map `<A-CR>` it doesn't work as expected.

However, the same mapping works on my terminal.

this is what I'm doing:
`:map <A-CR> :echo 1<cr>`

It behaves as if I was just pressing enter.

I tried `<M-CR>` and got the same result.

#### Edit:

I'm running Windows 10, vim 7.4, my .vimrc shouldn't matter because I get the same issue with the default config.

Comment: Have you tried `<M-CR>` instead?

Comment: @ryuichiro, yes (edited)

Comment: Add system details please

Comment: @sidyll, edited... are those details enough?

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598113/can-terminals-detect-shift-enter-or-control-enter gVim forces lots of problems on the user to try to stay in sync with terminal Vim

Comment: @OrlandoWilliam Certainly, and sorry that I can't help better, I thought you were on a Mac...

Comment: Got the same result using a friend's PC with a fresh install of vim 7.4

Comment: It seems quite problematic: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Mapping-lt-M-CR-gt-doesn-t-work-td1161482.html.