# How to bind CTRL + Enter in zsh?

Tags: zsh, gnome-terminal

I want to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> in zsh:

```
bindkey '^M' autosuggest-execute
```

But it seems that the terminal sends the same escape sequence for any modifier key except for <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

```
$ showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^M       13 0015 0x0d # Enter
^M       13 0015 0x0d # CTRL  + Enter
^M       13 0015 0x0d # SHIFT + Enter
^[^M     27 0033 0x1b # ALT   + Enter
         13 0015 0x0d
```

I am not sure if the problem is specific to `gnome-terminal`. I have also tested this in `mate-terminal` and `xterm` and the results were the same. Is there any way to detect `CTRL + Enter`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can terminals detect <Shift-Enter> or <Control-Enter>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598113/can-terminals-detect-shift-enter-or-control-enter)

Comment: @Adaephon It is similar. But in my case the terminal does not see `CTRL + Enter` as `<NL>` but as `^M`  which is the same for `Enter` and `SHIFT + Enter`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution for xterm, gnome-terminal and any other terminal emulator for the XWindow system.

Note that mapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to a specific shell command can be specifically done with xterm, in a specific way that has no impact on other terminal emulators running on the same X Server. With gnome-terminal, there is a more generic solution, but it will apply simultaneously to every terminal emulators on your XWindow server, not only gnome-terminal. So, depending on your needs, you have to choose one of these two solutions.

**First, here is the solution that fits specifically with xterm:**

Let's bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to a sequence that is not already bound by other combinations: with xterm, this can be done by specifying some X resources to populate the translations table. For instance, bind to <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. Then, use bindkey in zsh to bind this specific sequence to your ZLE function (`autosuggest-execute` according to you question).

To try, just follow those steps:

1- launch xterm this way:

```
% xterm -xrm '*.VT100.translations: #override Ctrl <Key>Return: string(0x1b) string("M")'
```

Note: we have used `Return`, but this is `Enter` that we will map this way.

2- in the new xterm window, use bindkey:

```
% bindkey '^[M' autosuggest-execute
```

3- now type CTRL-Enter to run autosuggest-execute

**Here is the more generic solution, for almost every terminal emulators**:

Like above, let's bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to a sequence that is not already bound by other combinations (we choose <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> here). Use the `Compose (5)` X11 mechanism: add a file $HOME/.XCompose  containing a specific mapping for the multi-key input sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. Then, use bindkey in zsh to bind this specific sequence to your ZLE function (`autosuggest-execute` according to your question).

To try, just follow those steps:

1- create a new file named $HOME/.XCompose

Add the following content in this file:

```
include "%L"
! Ctrl <Return> : "\033M"
```

Note 1: we have used `Return`, but this is `Enter` that we will map this way.

Note 2: the `!` is not a comment mark, it is important to keep it at the beginning of this line.

Note 3: the first line (`include...`) is here to keep other shortcuts working (for instance ^ + e mapped into ê).

2- now, you can launch gnome-terminal

3- in the new gnome-terminal window, use bindkey:

```
% bindkey '^[M' autosuggest-execute
```

4- now type CTRL-Enter to run autosuggest-execute

Comment: The xterm solution works, but I can't get it to work with gnome-terminal.
It seems that the `~/.XCompose` file is not being loaded. I tried `export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim` but still no luck

Comment: the generic solution doesn't work for me. I get the error `GTK+ supports to output one char only: "\033M": ! Ctrl <Return> : "\033M"` when running `im-config`

Comment: The generic solution worked well for me using a minimal i3/alacritty system.