# How do you open vimwiki in a new split?

Tags: vim, vimwiki

I'd like to be able to open my wiki in a similar way that `:vsplit some/file.md` works.

Comment: I believe that's for when vimwiki is already open, but how do you initially open vimwiki in a vertical split? I can only find a way to open it in the current buffer or a new tab, but not a vsplit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a known issue with some terminals, as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598113/can-terminals-detect-shift-enter-or-control-enter).

You can still remap the command if you'd like, for example:

```
:nmap <Leader>vs <Plug>VimwikiVSplitLink
```

Or if it does not interfere with your bindings:

```
:nmap <Leader>vs :VimwikiVSplitLink<CR>
```

**EDIT**

Now that I finally understood your request, to launch `vimwiki` from `vim` in a split you can just chain commands, i.e.:

```
:sp | :VimwikiIndex
:vs | :VimwikiIndex
```

This should do the trick.

For remapping, as @DavidVII pointed out, just escape the `|`:

```
nmap <Leader>vs :vs \| :VimwikiIndex<CR>
```

Comment: I attempted this command, but it does not appear to do anything. I'm using iTerm2.

Comment: I added an alternative version. Can you check if that works?

Comment: When I run that I get the following error `E492: Not an editor command: VimwikiVSplit`

Comment: It's [`VimwikiVSplitLink`](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/master/doc/vimwiki.txt#L770), not `VimwikiVSplit`.

Comment: Ops.. fixed that, thank you.

Comment: I'm getting same error with that too `E492: Not an editor command: VimwikiVSplitLink` I'm wondering if I missed a step in the installation process. I installed vimwiki with vim-plug, but that's it. Is there some other configuration I need to do in order to get those commands?

Comment: I've also tried this: `nmap <Leader>vs <Plug>VimwikiVSplitLink<CR>` [as described here](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/master/doc/vimwiki.txt#L142) and the error going away, but then nothing happens.

Comment: Naive question, but have you actually launched `vimwiki`, i.e. `<leader>ww`? And then tried the commands? If so, your installation is probably broken.

Comment: I'm understanding the confusion. That commands works once I have vimwiki open and want to open a link in a new split. What I'm after is opening the original window in a split. I want `<leader>ww` to open in a split, not the current window.

Comment: Oh... I was not getting that. I added one way to do that.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks for bearing with me. I really appreciate it 

Comment: One more request if I may, could you update your answer with an example of how to map that command? Not sure I've nmap'd a pipe command like that before.

Comment: Something like this in `~/.vimrc` should work and may be useful for folks in the future: `nmap <Leader>vs :vs \| :VimwikiIndex<CR>`